# char* to integer implementation (atoi with saturation to INT_MIN or INT_MAX on overflow)

Tags: beginner, c

I am learning C. As a task, I need to write a `get_int` function that will convert a `char*` to `int`. What parts can I improve here?  I'm especially interested in how I can improve/rewrite the overflow checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MINIUNIT_MAIN
// https://github.com/urin/miniunit/blob/master/miniunit.h
#include "miniunit.h"

int get_int(char *string) {
  int i = 0;

  while (isspace(string[i])) {
    i++;
  }

  char sign = string[i] == '-' ? '-' : '+';
  if (string[i] == '-' || string[i] == '+') {
    i++;
  }

  int result = 0;

  while (string[i] != '\0' && isdigit(string[i])) {
    // Check for overflow
    if (INT_MIN / 10 > result || (INT_MIN / 10 == result && INT_MIN % 10 >= -(string[i] - '0'))) {
      return sign == '-' ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
    }

    result = result * 10 - (string[i] - '0');

    i++;
  }

  return sign == '-' ? result : -result;
}

int main(void) {
  test_case("Simple numbers", {
    expect("0", get_int("0") == 0);

    expect("1", get_int("1") == 1);

    expect("12", get_int("12") == 12);

    expect("199", get_int("199") == 199);

    expect("1000", get_int("1000") == 1000);

    expect("214748364", get_int("214748364") == 214748364);

    expect("214748500", get_int("214748500") == 214748500);
  });

  test_case("Invalid input", {
    expect("Empty string", get_int("") == 0);

    expect("Spaces", get_int("   ") == 0);

    expect("Spaces and numbers", get_int("   123") == 123);

    expect("Plus sign", get_int("+") == 0);

    expect("Minus sign", get_int("-") == 0);

    expect("Letters", get_int("abc") == 0);

    expect("Letters and numbers", get_int("123abc") == 123);

    expect("Dot and numbers", get_int("123.4") == 123);
  });

  test_case("Negative numbers", {
    expect("-0", get_int("-0") == 0);

    expect("-1", get_int("-1") == -1);

    expect("-5", get_int("-5") == -5);

    expect("-12", get_int("-12") == -12);

    expect("-1000", get_int("-1000") == -1000);
  });

  test_case("Overflows", {
    expect("INT_MAX", get_int("2147483647") == INT_MAX);

    expect("INT_MAX + 1", get_int("2147483648") == INT_MAX);

    expect("INT_MAX + 10", get_int("2147483657") == INT_MAX);

    expect("INT_MAX + 1000", get_int("2147484647") == INT_MAX);

    expect("INT_MIN", get_int("-2147483648") == INT_MIN);

    expect("INT_MIN - 1", get_int("-2147483649") == INT_MIN);

    expect("INT_MIN - 10", get_int("-2147483658") == INT_MIN);

    expect("INT_MIN - 1000", get_int("-2147484648") == INT_MIN);
  });
}
```

Comment: Not worth a whole answer, but the parameter should be `const char*`

Comment: Also, odd that you would rely on `isspace(0)` to return `false` in one loop, and then carefully protect against testing `isdigit(0)` in the next

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Uncommon bug:  `is...()`**

`is...()` expects to receive an `int` with a value in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF`.  `char` values may be other negatives which results in *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
//  while (isspace(string[i])) {
while (isspace(((unsigned char *)string)[i])) {
```

**Pedantic bug: Long strings**

`int i = 0;` better as `size_t i = 0` for strings whose length exceeds `INT_MAX` as in pathological input `"000...3 billion zeros... 123"`.

**Overflow checking correct.**

Test is good and works for `int` of various width and encodings.

Consider a stronger `&&` test.  It may help performance as first test `INT_MIN / 10 > result` is commonly false.

```
// if (INT_MIN / 10 > result || (INT_MIN / 10 == result && INT_MIN % 10 >= -(string[i] - '0'))) {
   if (INT_MIN / 10 >= result && (INT_MIN / 10 > result || INT_MIN % 10 >= -(string[i] - '0'))) {
```

**Misleading comment**

`// Check for overflow` also is the return path for valid input like `get_int("-2147483648")`.

**Name**

`get_int()` sounds incorrect as `get...()` is often an I/O function.  Maybe `my_atoi()`.

**Consider assigning `errno` so caller can distinguish good from bad.**

On overflow and no conversion consider setting `errno`.

Maybe also invalid arguments and/or trailing non-numeric non-white-space text.

---

**Sample tested alternative**

- Use `const`.
- Stronger first range test.  `&&`
- Add error indication when possible.
- Take advantage that `isdigt('\0')` is false.
- Stronger tests for argument validity.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int atoint_alt(const char *string) {
  // Maybe check argument?
  if (string == NULL) {
#ifdef EINVAL
    errno = EINVAL;
#endif
    return 0;
  }
  
  bool digit_found = false;
  const unsigned char *ustring = (const unsigned char*) string;

  while (isspace(*ustring)) {
    ustring++;
  }

  bool isneg = *ustring == '-';
  if (isneg || *ustring == '+') {
    ustring++;
  }

  int result = 0;

  while (isdigit(*ustring)) {
    int digit = *ustring - '0';
    digit_found = true;
    // Check for overflow
    if (result <= INT_MIN / 10
        && (result < INT_MIN / 10 || digit > -(INT_MIN % 10))) {
      errno = ERANGE;
      return isneg ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
    }
    // Accumulate the value on the negative side.
    result = result * 10 - digit;
    ustring++;
  }

  if (!digit_found) {
#ifdef EINVAL
    errno = EINVAL;
#endif
    return 0;
  }

  if (!isneg) {
    if (result < -INT_MAX) {
      errno = ERANGE;
      return INT_MAX;
    }
    result = -result;
  }

  // Maybe look for extra junk
  while (isspace(*ustring)) {
    ustring++;
  }
  if (*ustring) {
#ifdef EINVAL
    errno = EINVAL;
#endif
    return 0;  // or maybe retval?
  }

  return result;
}
```

Note: `INT_MIN / 10` and `INT_MIN % 10` have some issues with pre-C99 code.  Look to `div()` to fix.

Comment: Thank you. I've learned many interesting nuances from your answer. It's somewhat surprising that the C allows for undefined behaviors.

Comment: @aliheym, Re UB: A strength/weakness of C is that it does not over-specify certain behaviors.  This has allowed C to focus on key behaviors without confining hardware/software technology to something that made sense at one time, but not another.

Answer (score 8):

The code is not bad and easy to follow.  Here are some suggestions:

### Use pointers rather than indexing

The `i` variable isn't really needed.  Instead, you could simply increment the pointer passed into your `get_int` function.

### Simplify variable usage

The `sign` variable is declared as a `char` and holds the sign, but every time it's used, it's compared with `'-'`.  I'd suggest comparing once and declaring it `bool` like this:

```
bool negative = *string == '-';
```

This simplifies usage as with the `return` statement:

```
return negative ? -result : result;
```

### Simplify overflow checking

**This was rewritten thanks to insightful comments.**
As was pointed out in the comments to the older version of this answer, you need to catch overflow *before* it happens, since if it happens, it's undefined behavior (UB).  This breaks the check into two pieces -- one for the multiplication and one for the addition.

```
for ( ; *string != '\0' && isdigit(*string); ++string) {
  if (result > INT_MAX/10) {
    return negative ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
  }
  result *= 10;
  if (result > INT_MAX - (*string - '0')) {
    return negative ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
  }
  result += (*string - '0');
}
```

### Consider an explicit error return

Right now, it's not possible to tell the difference between an actual conversion resulting in 0 or if it's an error.  Even more potentially confusing for users is that `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX` might be returned either as an actual calculated value or as an error indicator.  There are many ways to handle this: one way, used by the library function `strtof`, is to set the global `errno` value, but there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385975/error-handling-in-c-code) as well.

### Use `const` when passing parameters

Since your function does not and should not modify the passed string, you can declare it `const` to let the caller know that is the case.

### Putting it all together

Applying all of these, here's the version I came up with:

```cpp
int get_int(const char *string) {
  for ( ; isspace(*string); ++string) {
  }
  bool negative = *string == '-'; 
  if (*string == '-' || *string == '+') {
    ++string;
  }
  int result = 0;
  for ( ; *string != '\0' && isdigit(*string); ++string) {
    if (result > INT_MAX/10) {
      return negative ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
    }
    result *= 10;
    if (result > INT_MAX - (*string - '0')) {
      return negative ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;
    }
    result += (*string - '0');
  }
  return negative ? -result : result;
}
```

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour in C, so the overflow check isn't guaranteed to work. An optimising compiler may even remove the check completely

Comment: Sign could just be -1 or 1, so you can just `return result * sign` or `if (sign < 0)`, etc.

Comment: Your overflow check is broken, it is possible  for `result` to be greater than `oldresult` even when there is overflow. Try running your code for input "6000000000"

Comment: Forcing an in-range value of `INT_MIN` to take the overflow early return path is a bit of trickery worthy of a comment and explanation in the answer prose.

Comment: Your mention of *two's-complement* seems totally immaterial, there are no operations here which fail on other representations (except the one that fails on all representations).

Comment: It would be better to test whether the difference between the old result and the maximum is less than what we’re adding. This does not have UB. Alternatively, you could store the magnitude in an `unsigned int`, whose behavior on overflow is well-defined to wrap around.

Comment: Thanks for the comments -- you're all correct and my answer was not.  I've revised and reposted.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica : Thank you!  I've incorporated your suggestions and also upvoted your answer.  `unsigned` doesn't help here, but it emphasizes that the value is always a non-negative value.

Comment: @Edward Code is indeed improved. `unsigned` does prevent UB.  Yet `return negative ? -result : result;` is a little tricky though.  When `negative` is true, code may be converting an `unsigned` value more than `INT_MAX` to an `int`. This implementation defined (ID) conversion "the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. (C spec)" is commonly as desired (wrap around) and code returns the expected `int` value.  Yet code is relying on ID behavior.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Generally you're right about the conversion from `unsigned` to `signed`, but in this particular case, the overflow checks prevent this, so there is no reliance on implementation-defined behavior here as far as I can see.  Note too that if the input string is `INT_MIN`, the overflow check causes `INT_MIN` to be returned as expected.

Comment: @Edward Counter example: `get_int("-1")` executes `return negative ? -result : result;` attempting to convert `UINT_MAX` to -1 on the return - ID behavior.  Same for `get_int("-2")` ...  Nothing to do with overflow checks.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No, in the case of "-1", the value of `result` is 1 until the `return`.  Is it possible you've misread the code?

Comment: @Edward Prior to the last line `return negative ? -result : result;`, `result` is 1, then `-` is applied, making the `unsigned` value `UINT_MAX`.  Then `UINT_MAX` is converted to an `int` (being the function return type). That is when code incurs the ID behavior of converting an out-of-`int` range value `UINT_MAX` to an `int`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think that's incorrect.  See http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149910/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-edward).

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but a sample test harness using standard library code.

Adjust to ignore `errno` compare.

```
int strtoi(const char *s, char **endptr, int base) {
  if (s == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  long y = strtol(s, endptr, base);
  if (y < INT_MIN) {
    y = INT_MIN;
    errno = ERANGE;
  } else if (y > INT_MAX) {
    y = INT_MAX;
    errno = ERANGE;
  }
  return (int) y;
}

int main() {
  const char *s[] = { //
          // Must match value and errno
          "-2147483649", "-2147483648", "-2147483647", "-10", "-1", "-0", "0",
          "+0", "1", "10", "2147483646", "2147483647", "2147483648", "+1",
          "+10", "+2147483646", "+2147483647", "+2147483648", " \t\v\n\r123",
          " 42\n",  //
          // Must match value
          "x", "6000000000", "    ", "", "+", "-" "--123", "123.4", "abc",
          "876-5304", NULL};
  size_t n = sizeof s / sizeof s[0];
  bool must_match = true; // Must match both vlaue and errno.
  int failure_count = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    errno = 0;
    int y0 = strtoi(s[i], 0, 10);
    int e0 = errno;
    errno = 0;
    int y1 = get_int0(s[i]);
    // int y1 = get_int_OP(s[i]);
    // int y1 = atoint_alt(s[i]);
    int e1 = errno;
    if (s[i] && s[i][0] == 'x') {
      must_match = false; // Only need match value.
    }
    if (y0 != y1 || (e0 != e1)) {
      bool fail = y0 != y1 || (must_match ? e0 != e1 : 0);
      failure_count += fail;
      printf("%d %9s ", failure_count, fail ? "fail" : "optional");
      printf("y0:%11d,%2d  y1:%11d,%2d <%s>\n", y0, e0, y1, e1,
          s[i] ? s[i] : "NULL");
    }
  }
  printf("Failure count %d\n", failure_count);
}
```

Sample output

```
0  optional y0:          0, 0  y1:          0,22 <x>
0  optional y0:          0, 0  y1:          0,22 <    >
0  optional y0:          0, 0  y1:          0,22 <>
0  optional y0:          0, 0  y1:          0,22 <+>
0  optional y0:          0, 0  y1:          0,22 <---123>
0  optional y0:        123, 0  y1:        123,22 <123.4>
0  optional y0:          0, 0  y1:          0,22 <abc>
0  optional y0:        876, 0  y1:        876,22 <876-5304>
0  optional y0:          0, 0  y1:          0,22 <NULL>
Failure count 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very familiar with the standard library yet, but I found some new interesting stuff.

Btw, it's a very clever approach to check overflow using long. When we have checked the bounds (`INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`), is the `(int) number` considered safe?

Comment: @aliheym Yes, after the check, the cast does not change the _value_.